# Close button is not closing the form properly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My form contains a `button` named as `close`. I just put the below code in the  close button click... Then the 2nd code set is for the form closing. But if I execute this when I click the `close` `button`  a `MessageBox` will appear. When I click the **"Yes"** button, the form is not closing  but if I click the **"Yes"** button *second time* the form will be closed. What is the reason? Can you, please, help me?

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Close This Form?", 
                        "Close Application", 
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", 
        //                 "Application Closed!", 
        //                  MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Activate();
    }
}

-------------------------------------   

private void frminventory_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Close This Form?", 
                        "Close Application", 
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Do not close/exit `Application`, but `Form`:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // On btnClose button click all we should do is to Close the form
  Close();
}

private void frminventory_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  // If it's a user who is closing the form...
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
    // ...warn him/her and cancel form closing if necessary
    e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Close This Form?", 
                               "Close Application", 
                                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Usually we ask *direct questions* to user (it's *unclear* what wrong things can arise if I just *"Close This Form"*), e.g.

```
private void frminventory_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  // Data has not been changed, just close without pesky questions
  if (!isEdited)
    return;

  // If it's a user who is closing the form...
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
    var action = MessageBox.Show(
      "You've edited the data, do you want to save it?"
       Text, // Let user know which form asks her/him
       MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

    if (DialogResult.Yes == action)
      Save(); // "Yes" - save the data edited and close the form
    else if (DialogResult.No == action)
      ;       // "No"  - discard the edit and close the form
    else
      e.Cancel = true; // "Cancel" - do not close the form (keep on editing) 
  }
}
```

Comment: my form containing a data grid  and if i  add details  to that data grid  and i click the close button without saving  the details will lost right? also same thing will happen in the form closing  click right?That's why i want to add a confirmation message for close button click and form closing event .

Comment: @sherin: yes, when form is about to be closed (`FormClosing` event) it's a very time to ask user if (s)he wants to save the changes and cancel closing if necessary. However, we usually ask it in *direct way*: "Do you want to save changes? Yes / No / Cancel" where "Yes" - save changes and close the form, "No" - discard the changes and close the form, "Cancel" - do not close the form.

Comment: sir,thanks for the code .but the problem is when make any changes with the data grid and click save button a message will appear like "saved" then also the form closing message box will appear what is the issue

Comment: @sherin: Yes, you have to support `isEdited` field, property etc. (set it to `true` if grid changed by user, set it to `false` within `Save`)

Answer (score 0):

So, because i can't comment, i would do something like this.

```
    //Create this variable
    private bool _saved = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething();
        _saved = true;
    }

    //Raised when the text is changed. I just put this for demonstration purpose.
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _saved = false;
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_saved == false)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?\nYou may have unsaved information", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                _saved = true;
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this can solve yor problem

Comment: ....thank you.can you give a code to display an edited row of a data grid to another data grid ?suppose data grid 1 contains some details when i make any changes with any row that entire row will display on other data grid.the code must be in cell value changed? please help me......

Comment: right now i am not able to help about that sorry. Consider creating a new topic about that. BTW, accept either mine or Smitry answer if that has solved your "Close" problem.